# Calling SubForm routine from another Form

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I have a form X which contains a Subform Y. There is a routine which is defined in the Y form. I need to call that routine from another form Z (which opens whenever user click on some button on subform Y) on closing event of this form Z. Form X is open. What I have tried till now is not working:

// in form Z

```
Call Forms("X").SomeRoutine
Call Forms("Y").SomeRoutine
```

But every time I am getting RunTime Error 2450 that Access can't find the form.

Comment: Refer to subform http://access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0031.htm make sure the sub / function is not private.

Comment: Make sure the form Sub is Public (Public SomeRoutine() ...); Then use Call MyForm.SomeRoutine to call it from outside the form.

Comment: yes sub /function is public only.

Comment: Call Forms!X!Y.SomeRoutine()

Comment: thanks .. i have tried it but its not working. .. :(

Comment: @Roland are you sure this way it will work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My *X* form includes a subform control named *Child1*.  *Y* is the form contained as a subform in *Child1*.

Form *Y* includes this `Public` VBA procedure:

```vb
Public Sub SomeRoutine()
    Debug.Print "this SomeRoutine in form " & Me.Name
End Sub
```

With the parent form (*X*) open in Form View, I can go to the Immediate window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd>) and call *SomeRoutine* like this ...

```vb
Forms!X!Child1.Form.SomeRoutine
this SomeRoutine in form Y
```

The key point is that I used the name of the subform **control** which contains the *Y* subform.  (Notice the letter `Y` is not even present in `Forms!X!Child1.Form.SomeRoutine`)

The subform control name may be the same as the name of the form it contains ... but it does not have to be the same.  Check yours to ensure you use the name of the control.

Answer (score 2):

It's `Forms!X!Y.Form.SomeRoutine` - you have to explicitly address the form

Answer (score 0):

Cant you just Friend it? like so

```
Friend Sub cmd_Click()
  'code
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
  Me.cmd_Click
End Sub
```